# Cargar un archivo csv a MySQL completo

Tags: mysql, csv

Estoy intentando subir archivos .csv a MySQL, pero al subir el archivo no carga los registros completos, por ejemplo de un archivo que contiene 100 registros solo sube 85.
Me gustaría saber si este error es alguna configuración en el servidor o algo anda mal con los archivos.
La instrucción que uso para subir el archivo es la siguiente:

```
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE 'RUTA DEL ARCHIVO'
INTO TABLE PRUEBA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\N'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Quita la parte que dice `LOCAL` y de ahí en más tu sintaxis es correcta, si aún así te falla, entonces es detalle de los registros que tengan algún caracter extraño que trunque la inserción de esa fila en específico

Comment: ¿Revisaste si hay algo raro en las filas 84, 85 ó 86, algo diferente a las líneas con las que ha funcionado?

Answer (score 2):

prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'RUTA DEL ARCHIVO'
INTO TABLE PRUEBA
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: tu respuesta esta bien pero creo que seria mejor explicando cada uno de los parametros

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta web:
[http://file2sql.com](http://file2sql.com?utm_source=es.stackoverflow&utm_medium=reply&utm_campaign=csv_mysql)

A partir de un fichero csv detecta tipos de datos y retorna un script mysql que crea la tabla.

Comment: Y ademas la popula.....